# Problems with Dropbox in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, dropbox

I'm having this issue when running dropbox daemon

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
```

also dropbox is not synchronizing properly, and a red circle appears in the bar above to indicate there is an error.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Where do you get that error message?

Comment: in the terminal